# Sending message from Main to Renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Could someone help me out here. I'm completely confused on how to solve this. I've now spent about a week trying to find a solution for this but have come up short and there appears to be a lack of a solid solution online. I've made a github repository trying to demonstrate the issue.

In short I've implemented a status bar in my application which i want to populate with various string messages. These messages would be sent from functions that are contained inside a js file that imports electron, which mean's it doesn't have direct access to the Renderer. So how would I send these messages to the Renderer. I'm assuming this needs to be done using the ContextBridge, but i have no clue how to successfully do this, so if your response is just linking me to the context bridge docs, don't bother, lol I've exhausted myself looking at that. The other alternative i was considering is using a custom event but but i'm not sure that would solve the problem either.

Here is a sample of what im trying to do along with repo on github. If you do a pull-request to fix the repo, ill gladly merge and keep the repo public for others to benefit from and share with the community. https://github.com/JokerMartini/statusbar

As a minor problem, im not sure why i can no longer call getPath from 'app' from within a js file that's not loaded into the render thread.

I trigger a method from Renderer

**index.vue**

```
const doWork = () => {
    window.messenger.doWork();
}
```

**electron-preload.js**

```
import { contextBridge } from "electron";

const messenger = require("../src/helpers/messenger");
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("messenger", messenger);
```

**messenger.js**

```
const { app } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

// using electron module to demonstrate this file can't be imported into renderer
export function showMessage(msg) {
  const dir = path.join(app.getPath("documents"), "presets");
  console.log(dir);
  // TODO: send message to renderer...
}

export function doWork() {
  console.log("Doing working...");

  // step 1: long process
  showMessage("Processing step 1...");

  // step 2: long process
  showMessage("Processing step 2...");

  // step 3: long process
  showMessage("Processing step 3...");
}
```

I'd like to display the messages sent from the main to renderer to be displayed in the status bar of

**main.vue**

```
<q-footer>
     <q-bar>
        <span class="text-caption">Show message here...</span>
    </q-bar>
</q-footer>
```

** UPDATE 01 **

For some reason my message is not being received in the Renderer. Here are my code changes

**electron-preload.js**

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  setStatus: (callback, func) =>
    ipcRenderer.on("set-status", (event, ...args) => func(...args)),
});
```

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <q-btn label="Show Message" @click="doWork" />
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({

  setup() {
    // send message for testing...
    const doWork = () => {
      window.electronAPI.setStatus("sfsfsdfsd");
    };

    // recieve status messages...
    window.electronAPI.setStatus("set-status", (data) => {
      console.log("STATUS:", data);
      // TODO $store.dispatch("....");
    });

    return {
      doWork,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A technique that works for me is *not* to use the `preload.js` script to define concrete implementations. Instead, I use the `preload.js` script to only define channel (names) that I can communicate with between the main and render threads. IE: Seperating your concerns. Implement your concrete functions within your main thread scripts and render thread scripts.

---

`preload.js`

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'message:update' // Here is your channel name
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

> Note: Though I do not use [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), you should get the gist of the below two files.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true, 
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
    
    // Send a message to the window.
    window.webContents.send('message:update', 'Doing work...');
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <span id="text-caption">Show message here...</span>
    </body>
    
    <script>      
        // Listen for message updates from the main thread.
        window.ipcRender.receive('message:update', (message) => {
            document.getElementById('text-caption').innerText = message;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great breakdown @midnight-coding I was curious to know, how can i send messages from other js files that may be running on main since webcontents is not available? Would i call `ipcRenderer.send("message:update", "hello world")`

Comment: @JokerMartini Move the creation of your window into its own file. Within that file, add a `get()` function to return the window object. IE: `function get() { return window; }`. Then, in any file that needs it, `require` the file and call `get()`. EG: `appMainWindow.get().webContents.send('message:update', 'hello world');`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512175/how-to-use-webcontents-send-function-of-electron-js-in-other-ipc-render-file/71533675#71533675) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Is it possible to use the ipcRenderer.send method though? Or that is for something else?

Comment: @JokerMartini Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Sort of... Within the `preload.js` script, the command `ipcRenderer.send(...)` is configured under the `ipcRender.send` key, therefore, in your render thread `.js` script files, you can call `window.ipcRender.send('channel:name', 'This is my data to send to the main thread');`. Using this `preload.js` script, there would be no need to try and directly use (in one form or another) `ipcRenderer.send(...)` as it is implemented via the `preload.js` script. Does this answer your comment question?

Comment: i am trying to send data from `main.js` to `renderer.js` when the app is launched via `mainWindow.webContents.send('data:someData', someData)`, but the signal does not seem to be emitted to or registered by `preload.js`? -.-a

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `ipcMain` (in the main process) and `ipcRenderer` (in the renderer process). If you compare your scripts to the examples at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc that is what is missing.

(There is a [section specifically on doing main to renderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-3-main-to-renderer).)

This did use to be clearer and simpler, but carried more potential for abuse. So best to ignore any online tutorials older than a year or so. (Though `contextBridge` is quite new, so if they mention it then they should be recent.)

Comment: Thanks Darren, you suggestion helped a little bit. I feel that i am very close. I updated my answer above if you could help me out at all since you seem to have a better understanding.